How to remove duplicate field outcome
I am running the following request.
database
|where sourceServiceName_s == ("xyz")
|where TimeGenerated between(datetime(2024-11-01) .. datetime(2024-12-03))
|take 1000

As result
Row 1 : AAA
Row 2 : AAA

I would like to have only one row with data AAA

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have tried the above scenario with the below sample data.
let database = datatable(
    sourceServiceName_s: string,
    TimeGenerated: datetime,
    dup_column: string,
    samp_column: string
)
[
    "xyz", datetime(2024-11-01T10:15:00), "AAA", "Value1",
    "xyz", datetime(2024-11-01T11:30:00), "BBB", "Value2",
    "xyz", datetime(2024-11-02T08:45:00), "AAA", "Value3",
    "xyz", datetime(2024-11-02T14:10:00), "CCC", "Value4",
    "xyz", datetime(2024-11-03T09:20:00), "AAA", "Value5",
    "xyz", datetime(2024-11-04T16:50:00), "BBB", "Value6",
    "xyz", datetime(2024-11-05T12:00:00), "DDD", "Value7",
    "xyz", datetime(2024-11-06T13:45:00), "AAA", "Value8",
    "No", datetime(2024-12-06T13:45:00), "AAA", "Value9"
];

If you want to drop the duplicates and get the data of only dup_column as output, you can use summarize on the same column. This will group all the duplicate rows of that column and gives the result as shown below.
database
| where sourceServiceName_s == "xyz"
| where TimeGenerated between (datetime(2024-11-01) .. datetime(2024-12-03))
| summarize by dup_column
| take 1000


But if your requirement is to get all the columns along with the specific column, you can use arg_min(<column_name>, *) or arg_max(<column_name>,*) on the summarization of dup_column.
database
| where sourceServiceName_s == "xyz"
| where TimeGenerated between (datetime(2024-11-01) .. datetime(2024-12-03))
| summarize arg_min(TimeGenerated, *) by RowName
| take 1000


You can see that it returned all the columns from the table but coming to rows, in each group of dup_column, only the latest of the TimeGenerated rows will be given as output. If you use arg_max(), then it will be old date in the column  TimeGenerated.
